# Monitor accumulated number of bytes written by a process in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, disk-space, sip

I need a way to monitor the accumulated total number of bytes written to the disk by a process via the terminal. I've looked around quite a bit, and found several answers either saying to use `pv`, or `iotop`. However, `pv` is not installed on macOS out-of-the-box, and the version of `iotop` installed on macOS lacks the `-a` *accumulated* switch.

On top of that `iotop` requires SIP be disabled in newer versions of macOS, meaning it won't work with an out-of-the-box Mac. I need a method using tools built into macOS, they *can* require root access, they *cannot* require any non-stock macOS dependencies, e.g. Macports/Brew based software. Preferably in the stock version of Bash.

Comment: @bmike This isn't a duplicate. I explicitly stated I require a way to monitor the *accumulated* number of bytes written by a process, *not* the process's write speed per second. As I mentioned, `iotop` has a switch for this on Linux, but the version built into Sierra doesn't mention or support that switch. I also need a way that doesn't require SIP be disabled.

Comment: Sounds good. If the API is private, your answer could likely be no or no one has publicly released / reverse engineeed this yet. No harm in having it sit here until someone invests time to make the tool or tool chain you seek.